# yeoman backbone generator - what does grunt server do?

Tags: backbone.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

When using the [yeoman backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone), I am not clear on how the grunt tasks work.

1. Where does `grunt server` run the application from? It appears to run from the .tmp folder.
2. Where does `grunt server:dist` run the application from? It appears to run from the dist folder, but in my case the app does not launch correctly. It is trying to `require` HomePage.js which is not found.
3. Where does `grunt server:test` run from? It runs "watch:livereload" and then does not launch a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you use `grunt server`, you run your application from app/ dir. app/ is where your pure, non-compiled, non-minified source code lives. You don't need to change anything inside the .tmp/
2. When you use `grunt server:dist`, you build your application from app/ to dist/ and run it from dist/. dist/ is your distributable application.
   If you have a js error with `grunt server:dist` and not `grunt server` make sure you put your js link between

   ```
   <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/main.js -->
   <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/HomePage.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```

   Because the build process will concat all these files and build a new one (scripts/main.js) without copy the content of app/scripts into dist/scripts.
3. `grunt server:test` run from app and basically does enough to create and serve your application for your test framework, Mocha, to execute your tests. That don't launch a browser because it only serve your application for your test framework.

*Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-apps-with-the-yeoman-workflow/*

Comment: Thanks for your insights. On the second point, I am using the RequireJS option in the backbone generator. So there is only one line that gets inside the build:js comments: `<script data-main="scripts/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>`. So there is something else that must be going wrong.